An Angle Chasing Problem Involving a Triangle and $2$ Exterior Points
Consider the Triangle $\triangle ABC$ with angle $\angle ABC=30 ^ \circ$ , $\angle ACB = 33 ^ \circ$.
Choose a point $D$ to be opposite side of $A$ with respect to $BC$ such that $\angle DBC = 126 ^ \circ, \angle DCB = 15 ^ \circ$.
Choose a point $E$ to be opposite side of $B$ with respect to $CD$, and $\angle EDC = 9 ^ \circ, \angle EAB = 57 ^ \circ$.
The image below represents the whole figure of the problem.

The problem is to find $\angle ECD$.
I already found that the answer is $12 ^ \circ$ (from geogebra), but I want some nice, geometric solution for it. (like langley triangle problems). Any ideas or suggestions are highly appreciated in advance.

Avoid using non-objective terms like "hard" for a question : something which is hard for somebody will look easy for another one...

What have you tried so far? Hint: the problem doesn't mention any lengths, so angle chasing is almost certainly the place to start

@ChrisLewis From Geogebra, Point E is apparently the exocenter of triangle BAC, and the triangle ACE is a equilateral. But I failed to rigorously prove neither of them.

This approach does not require any additional auxiliary lines. Although it may seem complex, it indeed works.
The main techniques used are the law of sines and the law of cosines.
Firstly, we consider $ \triangle ACH $ and $ \triangle ABH $ in $ \triangle ABC $. Notice they share the same side $AH$, this can be useful (for simplicity in calculations, let us assume $AH = 1$ unit):
In $ \triangle ACH $:
$$
\frac{AH}{\sin 33^\circ} = \frac{CH}{\sin 60^\circ}
$$
therefore,
$$
CH = \frac{\sin 60^\circ}{\sin 33^\circ} \cdot AH
$$
In $ \triangle ABH $:
$$
\frac{AH}{\sin 30^\circ} = \frac{BH}{\sin 57^\circ}
$$
therefore,
$$
BH = \frac{\sin 57^\circ}{\sin 30^\circ} \cdot AH
$$
Since we have $BH$ and $HC$,
$$
BC = BH + HC = (\frac{\sin 57^\circ}{\sin 30^\circ}+\frac{\sin 60^\circ}{\sin 33^\circ}) \cdot AH = 3.2674317245328
$$
Secondly, we can examine the triangles within $ \triangle DBC $:
In $ \triangle GCH $:
$$
\frac{CH}{\sin 72^\circ} = \frac{GC}{\sin 93^\circ}
$$
therefore,
$$
GC = \frac{\sin 93^\circ}{\sin 72^\circ} \cdot CH = \frac{\sin 93^\circ}{\sin 72^\circ} \cdot \frac{\sin 60^\circ}{\sin 33^\circ} \cdot AH
$$
In $ \triangle BCD $:
$$
\frac{DC}{\sin 126^\circ} = \frac{BC}{\sin 39^\circ}
$$
therefore,
$$
DC = \frac{\sin 126^\circ}{\sin 39^\circ} \cdot BC = \frac{\sin 126^\circ}{\sin 39^\circ} \cdot (\frac{\sin 57^\circ}{\sin 30^\circ}+\frac{\sin 60^\circ}{\sin 33^\circ}) \cdot AH
$$
Since we have $GC$ and $DC$,
$$
DG = DC - GC = (\frac{\sin 126^\circ}{\sin 39^\circ}(\frac{\sin 57^\circ}{\sin 30^\circ}+\frac{\sin 60^\circ}{\sin 33^\circ}) - \frac{\sin 93^\circ}{\sin 72^\circ}\cdot \frac{\sin 60^\circ}{\sin 33^\circ}) \cdot AH = 2.5307876830175
$$
Lastly, let's explore the pair of triangles closely related to $\angle x$:
In $ \triangle DEG $:
$$
\frac{DE}{\sin 72^\circ} = \frac{DG}{\sin 99^\circ}
$$
therefore,
$$
DE = \frac{\sin 72^\circ}{\sin 99^\circ} \cdot DG = 2.4369247042
$$
In $ \triangle DEC $ we use law of cosines because we already know $DE$ and $DC$:
$$
CE^2 = DE^2 + DC^2-2 \cdot DE\cdot DC\cdot \cos 9^\circ
$$
therefore,
$$
CE = 1.833562177
$$
Use the law of sines again,
$$
\frac{CE}{\sin 9^\circ} = \frac{DE}{\sin x}
$$
we find that $x = \arcsin(\frac{2.4369247042}{1.833562177} \cdot sin 9^\circ) = 12^\circ$
By the way, this is my first time answering questions on MSE. If there are any inadequacies, please feel free to point them out. I hope my answer helps!

Welcome to Stack Exchange! This is a very thorough and well-written answer. Is there anyway that you could embed the picture within the text rather than providing a link - users will probably not like to click on third party links!

@TopologyTitan I've tried...but it says i need to earn 10 reputations to upload a picture. I'm sorry about that TAT. Perhaps we can refer to the image in the previous answer, my points G and H correspond to points P and S in that picture

Ah no problem! I didn’t realise that! It’s a good answer regardless

@TopologyTitan Thank you for pointing out this issue! I've now earned enough reputation points, so I've edited the answer to include the picture :)

@Tengy Thanks for your well-written answer! I thought that I might solve this by trigonometry, but don't know how. and you have shown the way how.

@Tengy The one thing I'm worrying about is, you have used some approximated values for sins and cosines. This might hurt the thoroughness of the solutions... so I will continue to search for geometric solutions.

@Cheese I agree that this can be an issue, so I keep many digits after the decimal point to significantly reduce errors. And I'm also curious about the solution that uses angle chasing.

Considering $\triangle ABC$ , the angles must be $30,33,180-33-30=117$ , hence $\angle EAC = 117-57=60$
Hence $\angle ASC = 180-60-33=87$ , while $\angle PSC = 180-87=93$
Considering $\triangle PSC$ , the angles must be $93,15,180-93-15=72$ , hence $\angle EPC = 180-72=108$
Considering Quadrilateral $DEAB$ , we have $DEA=360-57-(126+30)-(39+9)=360-57-156-48=99$
Except for $x$ & the angle marked "??" , everything is known :

Can you take it from here ?

Unfortunately, This kind of problem almost necessarily needs extra auxilary lines or transformation such as rotation or reflexion. So, by using only some direct angle chasing (e.g. sum of interior angles of a triangle=180), It doesn't help so much.
But thanks for your interest about this problem! I appreciate it.

That is right , @Cheese , here we have to show that $\triangle CEA$ is Equilateral. Equivalently , we have to show that at least two sides of the triangle are Equal. Then "??" is $60$ while $x=60-33-15=12$

You're totally right. but i failed to prove it while i have tried various attempts...
